# Automatic tabulation when writing code on Gedit?

Tags: gedit

Is there a way to modify the program in a way that it can auto tabulate to my actual indentation point while writing code on gedit?

For example, I'm writing an if statement like this and the program only does jumps directly to the beginning of the next line

```
if (number1 > number2)
{
...
}
```

But what I want the program to do is auto indent the lines for me (Like in any other IDE)

```
...
if (number1 > number2)
{
...
}
```

Is there a way in which I can told the program to do so. I know that many IDEs do this, but can I modifiy it? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `gedit` automatic indentation. From the top bar menu select `Edit`->`Preferences`->`Editor` and this screen appears:

[image: gedit preferences.png]

Click the second check box "**Enable automatic Indentation**". Then when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of a line, the next line is indented to the same level.